# JS Fetch API disable SSL certificate

Tags: javascript, certificate, fetch-api

I am using Fetch API to get the content of the URL. For my internal development I am trying to connect to a dev server and I get an error.

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “xxx.com” which could
>   put your confidential information at risk.

How can I disable SSL / Certificate check for internal purpose? Alternately I have a xxx.crt file, how do I install it or pass it to get a success response.

Comment: can you use http: instead of https: on the dev server

Comment: Nope, the server is not configured to work on Http .

Answer (score 0):

If there is any certificate mismatch, you should adapt your call to the server configuration. Update your dev machine 'hosts' file, adding a line with the server IP address and xxx.com.